# Unable to do if-else condition , session value overlapped

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script>
function gotoDetail(Request)
{   <%  HttpSession AtaSession =  request.getSession(true);%>
    if(Request=="DRY"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","DRY");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="GAX"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","GAX");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="GAZ"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","GAZ");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="RD"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","RD");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="RAG"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","RAG");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="RFR"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","RFR");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="TNK"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","TNK");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }else if(Request=="C_totalEUS"){
        <%AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","C_totalEUS");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }
}
```

Hi, above code is from my project , i'm using notepad++ to enhance this project. The trouble i having now is  when the parameter assign is (request == "DRY") the session should be equals to DRY , but the result to me equals to "C_totalEUS".
Is it there have any method to solve this ?Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are using jsp scriplets with javascript, kindly don't do that. Since jsp scriplets are evaluated before javascript, the every last statement is executed as `AtaSession.setAttribute("LoadPort","C_totalEUS")`.

***Edited***

You might make a call to another servlet or jsp to set the session attribute.

```
function gotoDetail(Request) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "put.jsp?LoadPort=" + Request;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
}
```

*put.jsp:*

```
<%session.setAttribute("LoadPort",request.getParameter("LoadPort"));%>
```

In case, if you can edit the same jsp i.e. `loadportbookingdetail.jsp`

```
function gotoDetail(Request) {
    window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp?LoadPort=" + Request);
}
```

*loadportbookingdetail.jsp:*

On the top of page

```
<%session.setAttribute("LoadPort",request.getParameter("LoadPort"));%>
```

Comment: Yes , exactly .. i found that they will execute the jsp scriplets separately  no matter what is the if-else condition are .. but any solution to solve this ? because im not familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check here.
1. the last else-if is not closed.
2. can you use any debug eg:console.log() and see where your control is going for the 'DRY' condition.
3. use small case for 'Request' just for better coding standards

eg:

```
function gotoDetail(request) {   
    <%  HttpSession session =  request.getSession(true);%>
    console.log('req='+request);
    if(request=="DRY") {
        console.log('DRY='+request);
        <%session.setAttribute("LoadPort","DRY");%>
        window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp");
    }
}
```

If you want to pass the value to next jsp.

JSP1:

```
   <script>

        function gotoDetail(req)
        {
            window.open("loadportbookingdetail.jsp?LoadPort="+req);
        }
    </script>
```

loadportbookingdetail.jsp:

```
<%=request.getParameter("LoadPort")%>
<% session.setAttribute("LoadPort",request.getParameter("LoadPort")); %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried already.. not working .. even the condition is true as the console.log display.